# Can't read old UFS1 superblock using GELI (Blowfish-CBC) on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, encryption

Trying to add encrypted partition on FreeBSD10.3 GELI/Blowfish-CBC. AES on / and /swap works fine, but I can't add an additional encrypted partition using Blowfish. Here is the way I did it:

```
# mount -o exec /dev/da2p1 /mnt/storekey
# gpart create -s gpt da1
da1 created
# gpart add -t freebsd-ufs -l usrdata da1
da1p1 added
# newfs gpt/usrdata
gpt/usrdata: 102400.0MB (209715128 sectors) block size 32768, fragment size 4096
        using 164 cylinder groups of 626.09MB, 20035 blks, 80256 inodes.
super-block backups (for fsck_ffs -b #) at:
 192, 1282432, 2564672, 3846912, 5129152, 6411392, 7693632, 8975872, 10258112, 11540352, 12822592, 14104832,
 15387072, 16669312, 17951552, 19233792, 20516032, 21798272, 23080512, 24362752, 25644992, 26927232,
 28209472, 29491712, 30773952, 32056192, 33338432, 34620672, 35902912, 37185152, 38467392, 39749632,
 41031872, 42314112, 43596352, 44878592, 46160832, 47443072, 48725312, 50007552, 51289792, 52572032,
 53854272, 55136512, 56418752, 57700992, 58983232, 60265472, 61547712, 62829952, 64112192, 65394432,
 66676672, 67958912, 69241152, 70523392, 71805632, 73087872, 74370112, 75652352, 76934592, 78216832,
 79499072, 80781312, 82063552, 83345792, 84628032, 85910272, 87192512, 88474752, 89756992, 91039232,
 92321472, 93603712, 94885952, 96168192, 97450432, 98732672, 100014912, 101297152, 102579392, 103861632,
 105143872, 106426112, 107708352, 108990592, 110272832, 111555072, 112837312, 114119552, 115401792,
 116684032, 117966272, 119248512, 120530752, 121812992, 123095232, 124377472, 125659712, 126941952,
 128224192, 129506432, 130788672, 132070912, 133353152, 134635392, 135917632, 137199872, 138482112,
 139764352, 141046592, 142328832, 143611072, 144893312, 146175552, 147457792, 148740032, 150022272,
 151304512, 152586752, 153868992, 155151232, 156433472, 157715712, 158997952, 160280192, 161562432,
 162844672, 164126912, 165409152, 166691392, 167973632, 169255872, 170538112, 171820352, 173102592,
 174384832, 175667072, 176949312, 178231552, 179513792, 180796032, 182078272, 183360512, 184642752,
 185924992, 187207232, 188489472, 189771712, 191053952, 192336192, 193618432, 194900672, 196182912,
 197465152, 198747392, 200029632, 201311872, 202594112, 203876352, 205158592, 206440832, 207723072, 209005312
# dd if=/dev/random of=/mnt/storekey/da0p1b.k bs=64 count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
64 bytes transferred in 0.000032 secs (1988411 bytes/sec)
# geli init -s 4096 -K /mnt/storekey/da0p1b.k -e Blowfish-CBC -a hmac/sha256 -l 448 gpt/usrdata
Enter new passphrase:
Reenter new passphrase:

Metadata backup can be found in /var/backups/gpt_usrdata.eli and
can be restored with the following command:

        # geli restore /var/backups/gpt_usrdata.eli gpt/usrdata
# geli attach -k /mnt/storekey/da0p1b.k gpt/usrdata
Enter passphrase:
# newfs gpt/usrdata.eli
gpt/usrdata.eli: 91022.2MB (186413448 sectors) block size 32768, fragment size 4096
        using 146 cylinder groups of 626.09MB, 20035 blks, 80256 inodes.
newfs: can't read old UFS1 superblock: read error from block device: Invalid argument
```

Ok, google said I need to destroy data with random output:

```
# dd if=/dev/random of=gpt/usrdata.eli bs=8m
dd: gpt/usrdata.eli: No such file or directory
```

Ok, I wanna check:

```
# geli list
Geom name: da0p4.eli
State: ACTIVE
EncryptionAlgorithm: AES-XTS
KeyLength: 128
Crypto: software
Version: 7
UsedKey: 0
Flags: BOOT
KeysAllocated: 50
KeysTotal: 50
Providers:
1. Name: da0p4.eli
   Mediasize: 26843378688 (25G)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Mode: r1w1e1
Consumers:
1. Name: da0p4
   Mediasize: 26843379200 (25G)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Stripesize: 0
   Stripeoffset: 1073891328
   Mode: r1w1e1

Geom name: gpt/swap.eli
State: ACTIVE
EncryptionAlgorithm: AES-XTS
KeyLength: 128
Crypto: software
Version: 7
Flags: ONETIME, W-DETACH, W-OPEN
KeysAllocated: 1
KeysTotal: 1
Providers:
1. Name: gpt/swap.eli
   Mediasize: 4294967296 (4.0G)
   Sectorsize: 4096
   Mode: r1w1e0
Consumers:
1. Name: gpt/swap
   Mediasize: 4294967296 (4.0G)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Stripesize: 0
   Stripeoffset: 1073891328
   Mode: r1w1e1

Geom name: gpt/usrdata.eli
State: ACTIVE
EncryptionAlgorithm: Blowfish-CBC
KeyLength: 448
AuthenticationAlgorithm: HMAC/SHA256
Crypto: software
Version: 7
UsedKey: 0
Flags: AUTH
KeysAllocated: 200
KeysTotal: 200
Providers:
1. Name: gpt/usrdata.eli
   Mediasize: 95443685376 (89G)
   Sectorsize: 4096
   Mode: r0w0e0
Consumers:
1. Name: gpt/usrdata
   Mediasize: 107374148096 (100G)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Stripesize: 0
   Stripeoffset: 17408
   Mode: r1w1e1
# ls /dev
acpi            da0p2           geom.ctl        mem             sndstat         ttyv9
apm             da0p3           gpt             midistat        stderr          ttyva
apmctl          da0p4           gptid           mpt0            stdin           ttyvb
atkbd0          da0p4.eli       hpet0           nfslock         stdout          ttyvc
audit           da1             io              null            sysmouse        ttyvd
bpf             da1p1           iso9660         pass0           ttyv0           ttyve
bpf0            da2             kbd0            pass1           ttyv1           ttyvf
bpsm0           da2p1           kbd1            pass2           ttyv2           ufssuspend
cd0             devctl          kbdmux0         pass3           ttyv3           urandom
console         devctl2         klog            pci             ttyv4           usbctl
consolectl      devstat         kmem            psm0            ttyv5           xpt0
ctty            fd              led             pts             ttyv6           zero
da0             fd0             log             random          ttyv7
da0p1           fido            mdctl           reroot          ttyv8
```

What's wrong? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use full device name:

```
dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/gpt/usrdata.eli bs=1m
newfs /dev/gpt/usrdata.eli
```

Got this solution here: https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/57051/#post-324890